# React.addons has undefined TestUtils (with Webpack Mocha Karma Babel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, karma-runner, mocha.js, babeljs

I don't understand why TestUtils is undefined when I require React/addons.

Karma log - look for undefined near the bottom of the stack trace.

 `gulp test:karma

[19:16:34] Using gulpfile ~/dev/react-starter/gulpfile.js
[19:16:34] Starting 'test:karma'...
DEBUG [config]: autoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining webpackPlugin, preprocessor:webpack).
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining framework:mocha).
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining launcher:Chrome, launcher:ChromeCanary, launcher:Dartium, test).
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining launcher:IE).
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining launcher:Firefox, launcher:FirefoxDeveloper, launcher:FirefoxAurora, launcher:FirefoxNightly).
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining launcher:PhantomJS).
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining preprocessor:sourcemap).
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/85/c3khd5g15nq5yy8_1m0s40y00000gn/T/karma-32579705
DEBUG [launcher]: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --user-data-dir=/var/folders/85/c3khd5g15nq5yy8_1m0s40y00000gn/T/karma-32579705 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate http://localhost:9876/?id=32579705
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/1/websocket/Yv-kuQa_TMT0ZHQtt4-A
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket Yv-kuQa_TMT0ZHQtt4-A
INFO [Chrome 41.0.2272 (Mac OS X 10.10.2)]: Connected on socket Yv-kuQa_TMT0ZHQtt4-A with id 32579705
DEBUG [launcher]: Chrome (id 32579705) captured in 3.444 secs
Hash: be6e75ac6e8a5e6d6ec9
Version: webpack 1.7.3
Time: 1270ms
                       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                        main   605 kB       0  [emitted]  main
test/front-end/hello-spec.js   834 kB       1  [emitted]  test/front-end/hello-spec.js
               bundle.js.map  1.02 MB    0, 1  [emitted]  main, test/front-end/hello-spec.js
chunk    {0} main, bundle.js.map (main) 582 kB
    [0] ./client/js/main.js 357 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./client/js/components/HelloComponent.js 485 bytes {0} {1} [built]
    [2] ./~/react/react.js 41 bytes {0} {1} [built]
    [3] ./~/react/lib/React.js 4.78 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [4] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginUtils.js 6.75 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [5] ./~/react/lib/ReactChildren.js 4.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [6] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponent.js 4.54 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [7] ./~/react/lib/ReactClass.js 30 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [8] ./~/react/lib/ReactContext.js 1.97 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [9] ./~/react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner.js 738 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [10] ./~/react/lib/ReactElement.js 8.27 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [11] ./~/react/lib/ReactElementValidator.js 14.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [12] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOM.js 3.26 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [13] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMTextComponent.js 3.59 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [14] ./~/react/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js 5.44 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [15] ./~/react/lib/ReactInstanceHandles.js 10.6 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [16] ./~/react/lib/ReactMount.js 31.2 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [17] ./~/react/lib/ReactPerf.js 2.55 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [18] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypes.js 11.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [19] ./~/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js 3.6 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [20] ./~/react/lib/ReactServerRendering.js 2.58 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [21] ./~/react/lib/Object.assign.js 1.26 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [22] ./~/react/lib/findDOMNode.js 2.4 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [23] ./~/react/lib/onlyChild.js 1.23 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [24] ./~/react/lib/EventConstants.js 1.56 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [25] ./~/react/lib/invariant.js 1.54 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [26] ./~/react/lib/PooledClass.js 3.27 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [27] ./~/react/lib/ReactFragment.js 5.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [28] ./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js 7.54 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [29] ./~/react/lib/warning.js 1.9 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [30] ./~/react/lib/ReactUpdateQueue.js 9.95 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [31] ./~/react/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js 843 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [32] ./~/react/lib/ReactInstanceMap.js 1.25 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [33] ./~/react/lib/ReactLifeCycle.js 1.25 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [34] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypeLocations.js 543 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [35] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypeLocationNames.js 612 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [36] ./~/react/lib/keyMirror.js 1.3 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [37] ./~/react/lib/keyOf.js 1.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [38] ./~/react/lib/emptyObject.js 483 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [39] ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeComponent.js 3.22 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [40] ./~/react/lib/getIteratorFn.js 1.18 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [41] ./~/react/lib/mapObject.js 1.47 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [42] ./~/react/lib/DOMPropertyOperations.js 6.03 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [43] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponentBrowserEnvironment.js 1.29 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [44] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js 16.9 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [45] ./~/react/lib/escapeTextContentForBrowser.js 850 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [46] ./~/react/lib/BeforeInputEventPlugin.js 15.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [47] ./~/react/lib/ChangeEventPlugin.js 11.5 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [48] ./~/react/lib/ClientReactRootIndex.js 551 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [49] ./~/react/lib/DefaultEventPluginOrder.js 1.34 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [50] ./~/react/lib/EnterLeaveEventPlugin.js 3.86 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [51] ./~/react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment.js 1.13 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [52] ./~/react/lib/HTMLDOMPropertyConfig.js 6.35 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [53] ./~/react/lib/MobileSafariClickEventPlugin.js 1.72 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [54] ./~/react/lib/ReactBrowserComponentMixin.js 715 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [55] ./~/react/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js 1.91 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [56] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMButton.js 1.61 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [57] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMForm.js 1.64 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [58] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMImg.js 1.41 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [59] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMIDOperations.js 5.49 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [60] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMIframe.js 1.37 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [61] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMInput.js 5.91 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [62] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMOption.js 1.34 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [63] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMSelect.js 5.21 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [64] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMTextarea.js 4.71 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [65] ./~/react/lib/ReactEventListener.js 5.51 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [66] ./~/react/lib/ReactInjection.js 1.47 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [67] ./~/react/lib/ReactReconcileTransaction.js 4.92 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [68] ./~/react/lib/SelectEventPlugin.js 5.84 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [69] ./~/react/lib/ServerReactRootIndex.js 868 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [70] ./~/react/lib/SimpleEventPlugin.js 12.5 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [71] ./~/react/lib/SVGDOMPropertyConfig.js 2.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [72] ./~/react/lib/createFullPageComponent.js 1.9 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [73] ./~/react/lib/ReactRootIndex.js 723 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [74] ./~/react/lib/DOMProperty.js 10.2 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [75] ./~/react/lib/ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js 12.3 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [76] ./~/react/lib/ReactEmptyComponent.js 2.83 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [77] ./~/react/lib/ReactMarkupChecksum.js 1.32 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [78] ./~/react/lib/ReactUpdates.js 9.26 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [79] ./~/react/lib/containsNode.js 1.23 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [80] ./~/react/lib/getReactRootElementInContainer.js 888 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [81] ./~/react/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js 4.54 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [82] ./~/react/lib/setInnerHTML.js 3.03 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [83] ./~/react/lib/shouldUpdateReactComponent.js 4.09 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [84] ./~/react/lib/emptyFunction.js 1.06 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [85] ./~/react/lib/ReactRef.js 2 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [86] ./~/react/lib/ReactServerRenderingTransaction.js 2.72 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [87] ./~/react/lib/isNode.js 718 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [88] ./~/react/lib/quoteAttributeValueForBrowser.js 747 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [89] ./~/react/lib/CSSPropertyOperations.js 5.31 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [90] ./~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js 12 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [91] ./~/react/lib/isEventSupported.js 1.98 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [92] ./~/react/lib/EventPropagators.js 4.65 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [93] ./~/react/lib/FallbackCompositionState.js 2.38 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [94] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticCompositionEvent.js 1.14 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [95] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticInputEvent.js 1.12 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [96] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginHub.js 8.23 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [97] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticEvent.js 4.85 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [98] ./~/react/lib/isTextInputElement.js 975 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [99] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticMouseEvent.js 2.2 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [100] ./~/react/lib/Transaction.js 9.36 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [101] ./~/react/lib/AutoFocusMixin.js 595 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [102] ./~/react/lib/LocalEventTrapMixin.js 1.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [103] ./~/react/lib/DOMChildrenOperations.js 4.51 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [104] ./~/react/lib/LinkedValueUtils.js 4.75 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [105] ./~/react/lib/EventListener.js 2.67 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [106] ./~/react/lib/getEventTarget.js 931 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [107] ./~/react/lib/getUnboundedScrollPosition.js 1.09 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [108] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponentEnvironment.js 1.7 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [109] ./~/react/lib/CallbackQueue.js 2.47 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [110] ./~/react/lib/ReactInputSelection.js 4.25 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [111] ./~/react/lib/ReactPutListenerQueue.js 1.33 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [112] ./~/react/lib/getActiveElement.js 788 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [113] ./~/react/lib/shallowEqual.js 1.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [114] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticClipboardEvent.js 1.22 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [115] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticFocusEvent.js 1.08 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [116] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticKeyboardEvent.js 2.72 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [117] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticDragEvent.js 1.09 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [118] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticTouchEvent.js 1.3 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [119] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticUIEvent.js 1.6 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [120] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticWheelEvent.js 1.99 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [121] ./~/react/lib/getEventCharCode.js 1.56 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [122] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginRegistry.js 8.92 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [123] ./~/react/lib/ReactEventEmitterMixin.js 1.32 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [124] ./~/react/lib/ViewportMetrics.js 638 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [125] ./~/react/lib/adler32.js 885 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [126] ./~/react/lib/isTextNode.js 614 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [127] ./~/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js 28.5 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [128] ./~/react/lib/ReactOwner.js 3.69 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [129] ./~/react/lib/CSSProperty.js 3.05 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [130] ./~/react/lib/camelizeStyleName.js 1.03 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [131] ./~/react/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js 1.93 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [132] ./~/react/lib/hyphenateStyleName.js 1.01 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [133] ./~/react/lib/memoizeStringOnly.js 778 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [134] ./~/react/lib/ReactMultiChildUpdateTypes.js 835 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [135] ./~/react/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js 4.17 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [136] ./~/react/lib/accumulateInto.js 1.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [137] ./~/react/lib/forEachAccumulated.js 889 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [138] ./~/react/lib/getTextContentAccessor.js 1 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [139] ./~/react/lib/getEventModifierState.js 1.33 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [140] ./~/react/lib/focusNode.js 728 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [141] ./~/react/lib/Danger.js 7.19 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [142] ./~/react/lib/setTextContent.js 1.19 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [143] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMSelection.js 6.14 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [144] ./~/react/lib/getEventKey.js 2.93 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [145] ./~/react/lib/camelize.js 714 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [146] ./~/react/lib/hyphenate.js 808 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [147] ./~/react/lib/flattenChildren.js 1.68 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [148] ./~/react/lib/createNodesFromMarkup.js 2.69 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [149] ./~/react/lib/getMarkupWrap.js 3.12 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [150] ./~/react/lib/getNodeForCharacterOffset.js 1.66 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [151] ./~/react/lib/createArrayFromMixed.js 2.37 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [152] ./~/react/lib/toArray.js 2.08 kB {0} {1} [built]
chunk    {1} test/front-end/hello-spec.js, bundle.js.map (test/front-end/hello-spec.js) 799 kB [rendered]
    [0] ./test/front-end/hello-spec.js 1.06 kB {1} [built]
    [1] ./client/js/components/HelloComponent.js 485 bytes {0} {1} [built]
    [2] ./~/react/react.js 41 bytes {0} {1} [built]
    [3] ./~/react/lib/React.js 4.78 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [4] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginUtils.js 6.75 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [5] ./~/react/lib/ReactChildren.js 4.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [6] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponent.js 4.54 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [7] ./~/react/lib/ReactClass.js 30 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [8] ./~/react/lib/ReactContext.js 1.97 kB {0} {1} [built]
    [9] ./~/react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner.js 738 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [10] ./~/react/lib/ReactElement.js 8.27 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [11] ./~/react/lib/ReactElementValidator.js 14.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [12] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOM.js 3.26 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [13] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMTextComponent.js 3.59 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [14] ./~/react/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js 5.44 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [15] ./~/react/lib/ReactInstanceHandles.js 10.6 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [16] ./~/react/lib/ReactMount.js 31.2 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [17] ./~/react/lib/ReactPerf.js 2.55 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [18] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypes.js 11.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [19] ./~/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js 3.6 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [20] ./~/react/lib/ReactServerRendering.js 2.58 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [21] ./~/react/lib/Object.assign.js 1.26 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [22] ./~/react/lib/findDOMNode.js 2.4 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [23] ./~/react/lib/onlyChild.js 1.23 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [24] ./~/react/lib/EventConstants.js 1.56 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [25] ./~/react/lib/invariant.js 1.54 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [26] ./~/react/lib/PooledClass.js 3.27 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [27] ./~/react/lib/ReactFragment.js 5.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [28] ./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js 7.54 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [29] ./~/react/lib/warning.js 1.9 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [30] ./~/react/lib/ReactUpdateQueue.js 9.95 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [31] ./~/react/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js 843 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [32] ./~/react/lib/ReactInstanceMap.js 1.25 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [33] ./~/react/lib/ReactLifeCycle.js 1.25 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [34] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypeLocations.js 543 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [35] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypeLocationNames.js 612 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [36] ./~/react/lib/keyMirror.js 1.3 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [37] ./~/react/lib/keyOf.js 1.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [38] ./~/react/lib/emptyObject.js 483 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [39] ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeComponent.js 3.22 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [40] ./~/react/lib/getIteratorFn.js 1.18 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [41] ./~/react/lib/mapObject.js 1.47 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [42] ./~/react/lib/DOMPropertyOperations.js 6.03 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [43] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponentBrowserEnvironment.js 1.29 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [44] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js 16.9 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [45] ./~/react/lib/escapeTextContentForBrowser.js 850 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [46] ./~/react/lib/BeforeInputEventPlugin.js 15.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [47] ./~/react/lib/ChangeEventPlugin.js 11.5 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [48] ./~/react/lib/ClientReactRootIndex.js 551 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [49] ./~/react/lib/DefaultEventPluginOrder.js 1.34 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [50] ./~/react/lib/EnterLeaveEventPlugin.js 3.86 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [51] ./~/react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment.js 1.13 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [52] ./~/react/lib/HTMLDOMPropertyConfig.js 6.35 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [53] ./~/react/lib/MobileSafariClickEventPlugin.js 1.72 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [54] ./~/react/lib/ReactBrowserComponentMixin.js 715 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [55] ./~/react/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js 1.91 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [56] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMButton.js 1.61 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [57] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMForm.js 1.64 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [58] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMImg.js 1.41 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [59] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMIDOperations.js 5.49 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [60] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMIframe.js 1.37 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [61] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMInput.js 5.91 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [62] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMOption.js 1.34 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [63] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMSelect.js 5.21 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [64] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMTextarea.js 4.71 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [65] ./~/react/lib/ReactEventListener.js 5.51 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [66] ./~/react/lib/ReactInjection.js 1.47 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [67] ./~/react/lib/ReactReconcileTransaction.js 4.92 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [68] ./~/react/lib/SelectEventPlugin.js 5.84 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [69] ./~/react/lib/ServerReactRootIndex.js 868 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [70] ./~/react/lib/SimpleEventPlugin.js 12.5 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [71] ./~/react/lib/SVGDOMPropertyConfig.js 2.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [72] ./~/react/lib/createFullPageComponent.js 1.9 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [73] ./~/react/lib/ReactRootIndex.js 723 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [74] ./~/react/lib/DOMProperty.js 10.2 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [75] ./~/react/lib/ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js 12.3 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [76] ./~/react/lib/ReactEmptyComponent.js 2.83 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [77] ./~/react/lib/ReactMarkupChecksum.js 1.32 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [78] ./~/react/lib/ReactUpdates.js 9.26 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [79] ./~/react/lib/containsNode.js 1.23 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [80] ./~/react/lib/getReactRootElementInContainer.js 888 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [81] ./~/react/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js 4.54 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [82] ./~/react/lib/setInnerHTML.js 3.03 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [83] ./~/react/lib/shouldUpdateReactComponent.js 4.09 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [84] ./~/react/lib/emptyFunction.js 1.06 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [85] ./~/react/lib/ReactRef.js 2 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [86] ./~/react/lib/ReactServerRenderingTransaction.js 2.72 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [87] ./~/react/lib/isNode.js 718 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [88] ./~/react/lib/quoteAttributeValueForBrowser.js 747 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [89] ./~/react/lib/CSSPropertyOperations.js 5.31 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [90] ./~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js 12 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [91] ./~/react/lib/isEventSupported.js 1.98 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [92] ./~/react/lib/EventPropagators.js 4.65 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [93] ./~/react/lib/FallbackCompositionState.js 2.38 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [94] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticCompositionEvent.js 1.14 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [95] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticInputEvent.js 1.12 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [96] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginHub.js 8.23 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [97] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticEvent.js 4.85 kB {0} {1} [built]
   [98] ./~/react/lib/isTextInputElement.js 975 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [99] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticMouseEvent.js 2.2 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [100] ./~/react/lib/Transaction.js 9.36 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [101] ./~/react/lib/AutoFocusMixin.js 595 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [102] ./~/react/lib/LocalEventTrapMixin.js 1.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [103] ./~/react/lib/DOMChildrenOperations.js 4.51 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [104] ./~/react/lib/LinkedValueUtils.js 4.75 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [105] ./~/react/lib/EventListener.js 2.67 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [106] ./~/react/lib/getEventTarget.js 931 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [107] ./~/react/lib/getUnboundedScrollPosition.js 1.09 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [108] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponentEnvironment.js 1.7 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [109] ./~/react/lib/CallbackQueue.js 2.47 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [110] ./~/react/lib/ReactInputSelection.js 4.25 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [111] ./~/react/lib/ReactPutListenerQueue.js 1.33 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [112] ./~/react/lib/getActiveElement.js 788 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [113] ./~/react/lib/shallowEqual.js 1.1 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [114] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticClipboardEvent.js 1.22 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [115] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticFocusEvent.js 1.08 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [116] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticKeyboardEvent.js 2.72 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [117] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticDragEvent.js 1.09 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [118] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticTouchEvent.js 1.3 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [119] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticUIEvent.js 1.6 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [120] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticWheelEvent.js 1.99 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [121] ./~/react/lib/getEventCharCode.js 1.56 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [122] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginRegistry.js 8.92 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [123] ./~/react/lib/ReactEventEmitterMixin.js 1.32 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [124] ./~/react/lib/ViewportMetrics.js 638 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [125] ./~/react/lib/adler32.js 885 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [126] ./~/react/lib/isTextNode.js 614 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [127] ./~/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js 28.5 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [128] ./~/react/lib/ReactOwner.js 3.69 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [129] ./~/react/lib/CSSProperty.js 3.05 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [130] ./~/react/lib/camelizeStyleName.js 1.03 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [131] ./~/react/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js 1.93 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [132] ./~/react/lib/hyphenateStyleName.js 1.01 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [133] ./~/react/lib/memoizeStringOnly.js 778 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [134] ./~/react/lib/ReactMultiChildUpdateTypes.js 835 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [135] ./~/react/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js 4.17 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [136] ./~/react/lib/accumulateInto.js 1.74 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [137] ./~/react/lib/forEachAccumulated.js 889 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [138] ./~/react/lib/getTextContentAccessor.js 1 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [139] ./~/react/lib/getEventModifierState.js 1.33 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [140] ./~/react/lib/focusNode.js 728 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [141] ./~/react/lib/Danger.js 7.19 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [142] ./~/react/lib/setTextContent.js 1.19 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [143] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMSelection.js 6.14 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [144] ./~/react/lib/getEventKey.js 2.93 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [145] ./~/react/lib/camelize.js 714 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [146] ./~/react/lib/hyphenate.js 808 bytes {0} {1} [built]
  [147] ./~/react/lib/flattenChildren.js 1.68 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [148] ./~/react/lib/createNodesFromMarkup.js 2.69 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [149] ./~/react/lib/getMarkupWrap.js 3.12 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [150] ./~/react/lib/getNodeForCharacterOffset.js 1.66 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [151] ./~/react/lib/createArrayFromMixed.js 2.37 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [152] ./~/react/lib/toArray.js 2.08 kB {0} {1} [built]
  [153] ./~/react/addons.js 51 bytes {1} [built]
  [154] ./~/chai/index.js 40 bytes {1} [built]
  [155] ./~/react/lib/ReactWithAddons.js 1.69 kB {1} [built]
  [156] ./~/chai/lib/chai.js 1.28 kB {1} [built]
  [157] ./~/react/lib/LinkedStateMixin.js 1.17 kB {1} [built]
  [158] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin.js 1.55 kB {1} [built]
  [159] ./~/react/lib/ReactCSSTransitionGroup.js 1.73 kB {1} [built]
  [160] ./~/react/lib/ReactTransitionGroup.js 6.3 kB {1} [built]
  [161] ./~/react/lib/cx.js 1.75 kB {1} [built]
  [162] ./~/react/lib/cloneWithProps.js 1.82 kB {1} [built]
  [163] ./~/react/lib/update.js 5.07 kB {1} [built]
  [164] ./~/chai/lib/chai/config.js 1.46 kB {1} [built]
  [165] ./~/chai/lib/chai/assertion.js 3.79 kB {1} [built]
  [166] ./~/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js 41.8 kB {1} [built]
  [167] ./~/chai/lib/chai/interface/expect.js 747 bytes {1} [built]
  [168] ./~/chai/lib/chai/interface/should.js 2.69 kB {1} [built]
  [169] ./~/chai/lib/chai/interface/assert.js 31.5 kB {1} [built]
  [170] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/index.js 1.62 kB {1} [built]
  [171] ./~/react/lib/ReactLink.js 2.03 kB {1} [built]
  [172] ./~/react/lib/ReactStateSetters.js 3.67 kB {1} [built]
  [173] ./~/react/lib/ReactCSSTransitionGroupChild.js 3.8 kB {1} [built]
  [174] ./~/react/lib/ReactTransitionChildMapping.js 3.27 kB {1} [built]
  [175] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTransferer.js 3 kB {1} [built]
  [176] ./~/chai/~/assertion-error/index.js 2.34 kB {1} [built]
  [177] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/test.js 500 bytes {1} [built]
  [178] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/type.js 1.09 kB {1} [built]
  [179] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/getMessage.js 1.3 kB {1} [built]
  [180] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/getActual.js 415 bytes {1} [built]
  [181] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/inspect.js 9.82 kB {1} [built]
  [182] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/objDisplay.js 1.2 kB {1} [built]
  [183] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/flag.js 787 bytes {1} [built]
  [184] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/transferFlags.js 1.29 kB {1} [built]
  [185] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/getPathValue.js 1.01 kB {1} [built]
  [186] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/getPathInfo.js 2.69 kB {1} [built]
  [187] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/hasProperty.js 1.51 kB {1} [built]
  [188] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/getName.js 429 bytes {1} [built]
  [189] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/addProperty.js 1.04 kB {1} [built]
  [190] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js 1.16 kB {1} [built]
  [191] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/overwriteProperty.js 1.51 kB {1} [built]
  [192] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/overwriteMethod.js 1.43 kB {1} [built]
  [193] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/addChainableMethod.js 3.6 kB {1} [built]
  [194] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/overwriteChainableMethod.js 1.71 kB {1} [built]
  [195] ./~/react/lib/CSSCore.js 3.66 kB {1} [built]
  [196] ./~/react/lib/ReactTransitionEvents.js 3.14 kB {1} [built]
  [197] ./~/react/lib/joinClasses.js 941 bytes {1} [built]
  [198] ./~/chai/~/deep-eql/index.js 39 bytes {1} [built]
  [199] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/getProperties.js 771 bytes {1} [built]
  [200] ./~/chai/lib/chai/utils/getEnumerableProperties.js 527 bytes {1} [built]
  [201] ./~/chai/~/deep-eql/lib/eql.js 4.87 kB {1} [built]
  [202] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js 36.7 kB {1} [built]
  [203] ./~/chai/~/deep-eql/~/type-detect/index.js 40 bytes {1} [built]
  [204] ./~/chai/~/deep-eql/~/type-detect/lib/type.js 2.75 kB {1} [built]
  [205] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/~/ieee754/index.js 2.09 kB {1} [built]
  [206] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/~/is-array/index.js 470 bytes {1} [built]
  [207] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/~/base64-js/lib/b64.js 3.57 kB {1} [built]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
    /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js
    /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/karma-mocha/lib/adapter.js
    /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/test/front-end/hello-spec.js
webpack: bundle is now INVALID.
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/karma-mocha/lib/adapter.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/test/front-end/hello-spec.js
LOG: 'test is ok'
LOG: 'log Object.keys(React.addons)', ['CSSTransitionGroup', 'LinkedStateMixin', 'PureRenderMixin', 'TransitionGroup', 'batchedUpdates', 'classSet', 'cloneWithProps', 'createFragment', 'update']
Chrome 41.0.2272 (Mac OS X 10.10.2) HelloComponent says hello in a class of hello FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderIntoDocument' of undefined
        at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/test/front-end/hello-spec.js:76:27)
Chrome 41.0.2272 (Mac OS X 10.10.2): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.013 secs / 0.002 secs)
DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /var/folders/85/c3khd5g15nq5yy8_1m0s40y00000gn/T/karma-32579705
[19:16:39] 'test:karma' errored after 4.76 s
[19:16:39] Error: 1
    at formatError (/Users/ivan/.nvm/v0.10.38/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/ivan/.nvm/v0.10.38/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
    at /Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
    at finish (/Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (/Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
    at removeAllListeners (/Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:220:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/ivan/dev/react-starter/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:231:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:180:16)`

The code is available here:

and this output can be reproduced with `npm install && gulp test:karma`

Comment: The open-source code is here: https://github.com/UWFosterIT/react-starter and the test is here: https://github.com/UWFosterIT/react-starter/blob/master/test/front-end/hello-spec.js

Comment: It's definitely something in my main `webpack.config.js`  - now on master I have manually specified the webpack config in `karma.conf.js` and it's working. So my question is which part of webpack.config.js is messing it up, and why?

Comment: Repo appears to be gone. Did you get this worked out?

Comment: Heh, haven't thought about this in a while. The repo moved to my github account here: https://github.com/ivanoats/react-starter